# A word with multiple definitions, one of which is dominant

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for a word with more than one definition, but where one of the definitions is dominant? When the word is used in conversation, that 'dominant' sense is assumed even when a different sense of the word is intended.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is unfortunately rather vague; you could be looking for *double entendre*, or *polysemy*, or *zeugma*, or other things. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] and edit this question to provide more background, and what your initial attemtps at research have found.

Comment: Do you mean, even if the word has to be interpreted in the other way in a conversation, people would still assume it in the widely accepted norm of the word?

Comment: I will use an example. If I said "he is mad," most people would assume that I am saying he is angry instead of not being mentally sound. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what I am saying. I once said that a friend of mine was mad off of her medication, and they thought I meant angry.

Comment: @Nicholas You want to be careful, I (BrE) would never assume that a speaker means 'angry' from *mad* I would always presume that they mean 'crazy'.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I've edited your question to give it a more useful title and clearer text. I've also replaced the tag with one that I think is more relevant to your question. I trust it's still in keeping with your intention. Please take a look, and feel free to roll it back to your previous version, or edit further.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, have a look at the [guidelines](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for these types of questions (you can hover your mouse over the tag and then click `info`). In particular, please add a sample sentence to your question.

Comment: By the way, you can get the attention of a user that you're replying to in comments by using the '@' convention (e.g. @Nicholas). This alerts the person to the comment. Without the leading '@', they may not know that you've replied to their comment.

Comment: You've got it :) . (Although I didn't use '@' in this comment, you were alerted because this comment was made under your post. It's one of the few auto-ping exceptions.)

Comment: @Lawrence I think the word starting with an "s" or a "c." Is there a dictionary that allows me to look at words and definitions like a book physical dictionary would?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are some resources that may be useful to you. Have a look at OneLook in particular - it has a reverse dictionary (you put in the meaning, it suggests the words). It's a little clunky, though.

Comment: Have a look also at the OED, 1st edition, which is linked under *dictionaries*. It seems to be downloadable in various formats, so you may be able to browse it the way you described, but be warned that the files are huge.

Answer (score 1):

As choster mentioned, polysemy could cover the issue. I know exactly what you mean. There should be a term for what you described, because I have wondered about that issue as well. There should be a term for the predominant meaning of a word. One example of polysemy is the word "constituent." When people say "constituent" in a political conversation, they are referring to a portion of voters. But when people say "constituent" in other contexts, the word means a portion of anything: such as, "Take note of the constituent minerals of this rock." But in political contexts, no one ever says "the constituency of donors," or "the constituency of allied countries." They only use "constituency" to refer to portions of voters, and not of any other group of people or items, even though the word "constituent" in other contexts simply means portion of the whole. People almost never use "constituent" unless they are in a political context, so that has somehow because the predominant meaning.

con·stit·u·ent
kənˈstiCHo͞oənt/Submit
adjective
1.
being a part of a whole.
"the constituent minerals of the rock"
synonyms:   component, integral; More
2.
being a voting member of a community or organization and having the power to appoint or elect.
"the constituent body has a right of veto"
noun
1.
a member of a constituency.
synonyms:   voter, elector, member of a constituency
"representatives must listen to their constituents"
2.
a component part of something.
"the essential constituents of the human diet"
synonyms:   component, ingredient, element; More